# Can I make google test return 0 even when tests fail?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am calling a googletest in the post-build step of a C++ project in VS 2012.

Naturally, when any of the tests fail, the googletest command returns failure (-1), and the entire project is marked as a failure by Visual Studio.

I do not want that.  I want the googletest to be run, and I want to see the results in the output, but I do not want to fail the project if not all tests pass.

Is there any flag that I can pass into googletest so that it always returns success (zero)?

Comment: You can't make googletest say it succeeds if it fails. So change the post-build step to call a script that runs the googletest, ignores its return code, and returns 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make the test return `0` if you write your own `main` function.

I imagine you're linking your test executable with the special `gtest_main` library which is a very basic helper to allow you to avoid having to write your own `main` function.

It's pretty much just doing:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n");
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The `RUN_ALL_TESTS` macro is the culprit which is returning `-1`, so all you need to do is stop linking with `gtest_main` and write your own `main` more like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return 0;
}
```

For more info on this topic, see [the GoogleTest docs](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_Primer#Writing_the_main%28%29_Function).